# Duplicate a javaws application to edit

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jnlp, jd-gui

I use an javaws app that comes with a jnlp file. I want to launch it locally and be able to modify the source code on my computer to fit my exact needs. I use Eclipse as IDE.

I've opened the jnlp file and downloaded all the jar files, then I have used JD-GUI and CFR to decompile the app.
In Eclipse, I've imported all the different ressources jar and put the app decompiled source code within the src folder. I've tried to correct every mistake done by both softwares but the app still crashes due to their mistakes.

Note, if i just import the app as a jar file, it works as expected but i can't edit the files, indeed it's a class file.

Comment: why do you need to modify source code of someone else application for your use ?

Comment: I need it because its an app createdby our teachers to help us tests our codes. Me and a friend are stucked at a point when the test is not working even if the result shown by the app is identical so i wanted to catch the thing that make it failed. It's been three days that i am looking for this "bug" just to know if its an app failed or my code's fault. Sorry if my english is not good

Comment: Go ahead and ask your teachers for the source code, then you are ready to go for editing; legally and technically.

Comment: I was asking because my teachers aren't answering, thats why i wanted to do it on my own.